# Ubuntu 16.04 python installing 3rd party module ffmpeg-3.0.2

Tags: python, module, ffmpeg, installation

Have tried installing this package multiple times. Initially I installed it to a directory where I am running scripts that call it but I get an error message "ImportError: No module named 'ffmpeg'".

I then tried putting it in one of my python paths listed in sys.path and again I got the same message.

I then opened .bashrc and added the home directory path and still got the same error message when I ran my script.

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ffmpeg

from PIL import Image

img = sys.argv[1] # ignore this

im = Image.open(img) # ignore this
imarray = np.array(im) # ignore this

ffmpeg -i ('flame.avi') -f image2 -c:v mjpeg ('image-%d.jpg')
avconv -i ('flame.avi') -vsync ('1') -r ('100') ('image%03d.tif')
```

I'm really not sure where to go, what are my options here? And what am I doing that is glaringly wrong?

Comment: You're mixing python and bash. What made you think you could do this the way you're trying to?

Comment: I tried installing the module using pip, then conda and neither of those worked. I then read the installation guide that comes with the package which says on linux: ./configure, make, sudo make install.

Comment: What 'module' do you think you need? There's only 3rd party python bindings to ffmpeg/libav. They don't ship with ffmpeg. And your code is not valid python, nor valid bash.

Comment: Can you please explain how I should fix this?

Comment: Do you actually know any python?

Comment: Yes I do, I'm trying to split an avi file into individual frames and all things pointed to ffmpeg. I downloaded that and extracted it to what I thought was the appropriate folder and installed it. I'm obviously missing something so if you can explain that to me I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Simplest solution then is to not try that in python 'natively', but just call the system ffmpeg (or libav) binary using sth like `subprocess.check_call(args)`

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll have to look up your solution as its not something I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you allready use Conda, than I would recommend installing pyav via Conda. Pyav has the python bindings (small programms) to run ffmpeg. Best of all as conda also installs the needed binaries, it also installs an ffmpeg to use.

If you just want to split your movie into a series of images you can do this from the bash using ffmpeg or libav's avconv

```
avconv -i ./SOURCE_NAME.avi -vsync 1 -r FRAMES_PER_SECOND -qscale 1 -an -y './PATH/TO_FILES/frame_%4d.jpg'
```

where -i demarks the source file |
-vsync 1 notes that their should be vertical synchronisation | -r is the frame rate of the movie | -qscale is the quality (1 being best and slowest) | -an -y no sound if I remeber correctly | then you give it the target destination where %4d means the frame number with 4 leading zeros, so files will be called frame_0001.jpg, frame_0002.jpg, etc.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for, much appreciated